# Jumping Spherical Robots

Tags: technology, robots

I have a robot. It's a perfectly spherical bot, sort of like the bottom of BB-8. It's around a foot and a half tall and weighs about 15 pounds. I need it to be able to jump on command, no matter which way is 'up.' It should jump at least a foot in the air, although higher is definitely allowed.

The mechanism must be fully internal, since anything pushing out of the robot wouldn't work at every angle (only if pointing straight down). No holes can be in the robot, so a rocket system wouldn't work.

The current system for movement is that it distributes weight to make the outside shell move. The internals are always right-side up due to gravity.

So how could a jumping mechanism work?

Comment: The center of mass of the robot cannot move, because an object at rest shall remain at rest unless an external force is acting upon it. The question asks for the outer shell to move more than it radius; since the center of mass cannot move, this means that at the top of the jump it will lie outside the robot. Sir Isaac Newton says no way, unless you allow the outer shell to flex; but this contradicts the requirement of a perfectly spherical robot -- it won't be spherical before jumping. If the outer shell is allowed to flex, then the robot can jump in the same way a human jumps.

Comment: "The mechanism must be fully internal, since anything pushing out of the robot wouldn't work at every angle (only if pointing straight down)." This doesn't need to be the case, so is it a rule (no external extendable parts) or can the ball have numerous legs that spring out in multiple directions?

Comment: @AlexP The external force is the normal force from the ground. The outer shell doesn't need to flex at all, you just need to quickly move mass from the bottom to the top completely within the spherical shell, and inertia will lift the whole thing off the ground. I don't see why the center of mass should be unable to move, this is no different from any other creature or machine that moves by pushing off the ground. Simply drawing a circle around a jumping human would seem to fit the bill (if they jumped high enough).

Comment: @DWKraus Yes, it is a requirement. I'm designing a video game character, and I made the actual shell before I thought about the internals!

Comment: Have you considered modeling your robots as frictionless antigravity spherical cows instead? (Oops, wrong community)

Comment: @AlexP: You can think of it as the entire Earth/Robot system whose center of mass can't move, since the two objects can apply forces on each other to move together or apart. A human can hold a mass at eye level, then drop it to hip level, without changing their "bounding box", but it's clearly shifting the center of gravity downward. Picking the mass back up shifts CoG upwards, again with no bounding box changes. As the human's CoG moves, the Earth's also moves a (very) small amount in the opposite direction.

Comment: @ItaiFerber what about  a little gnome sitting on top, bumping the robot foward ? https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=skippybal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Linear motor in z axis

So essentially this functions like a monowheel motorcycle except 3d rather then 2d.

Then the easiest way to make it jump is have a linear motor with movement in the z axis and significant mass moved. The jump mechanism would be attached to the inner drive carriage which would allow for it to have consistent 'up' direction.

Probably something like at least 10% of total mass to maybe 30%. Perhaps the energy storage unit. The higher the mass the more care will need to be for at rest placement of the mass. If that mass is too high position wise, up could become down.

Some pattern of moving the mass rapidly will get a jump. To get higher jumps the mass will have to be moved faster.

Answer (score 20):

/The current system for movement is that it distributes weight to make the outside shell move./

**Redistribute weight energetically against the interior top of the sphere.**

Your sphere contains a weight that can move.  It is a hamsterball.    To make its sphere jump, the robot hamster pushes off mightily against the inside of the sphere where it is against the ground.  It jumps into the air.  Now the robot hamster is hurtling upwards within the sphere, squealing shrilly.  When its weight impacts the apex of the sphere interior, its kinetic energy is transmitted to the sphere as a whole.  The sphere lifts off the ground.

Assuming the sphere is elastic to some degree (steel?) it might bounce when it comes back down.  Your interior robot hamster will come back down first because it bounced off of the interior apex when it hit.  If your hamster can time its next jump to be when the sphere hits the ground, the sphere will rise higher the second time than the first because your robot hamster is adding its energy the second time to some of the energy left from the first.  Such a ball could bounce higher and higher with each bounce.

Comment: This is just like the movement of Mexican Jumping Beans (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_jumping_bean) Although it should be noted this only works when it has ground (with sufficient gravity) to push against.

Comment: @PipperChip Gravity is not required, just a surface to push off of. Gravity is convenient for making contact with a surface, but isn't required to push - astronauts on the ISS can push off the walls despite being in freefall.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie My mistake. The caveat here is that the internal mass shifting around needs to move the position of the center-of-mass of the hamster+ball system enough that there is interference with whatever surface the robot is jumping from. (The material resisting deformation is how a normal force is produced and astronauts can push off surfaces.) If the 'hamster' is not massive enough, this isn't effective.

Comment: You could also use similar manipulation of the internals to _dampen_, rather than amplify a potential bounce if bouncing is not the desired behavior.

Comment: the hamster will reflect back towards the bottom, which is moving upwards. when they collide, the upwards motion is stopped. this will happen before the whole assembly will have travelled more than the diameter of the sphere.

Comment: The hamster doesn't have to hit the top of the sphere, it just needs to exert force on it in some way, for example by grabbing handles on the side of the sphere.

Answer (score 14):

**Lightning.**

OK, ambiguous answer title, but a sudden high-voltage large-Coulombe charge developed between the centre of the sphere and the outside would have the knock-on effect of creating a charge-differential between earth and the outside of the sphere. The nature of the amount of a single charge is limited by the surface area of the sphere.

A flash discharge between the sphere and ground would then result in the expansion of enough of the ground surface-material as a gas-plasma, providing an impulse upwards. Because a single discharge of the sphere's capacity to store charge wouldn't be sufficient to do the job, a fast alternating charge (perhaps in the order of hundreds of thousands or millions of times per second) is continually applied so that repeated strikes up, down, up occur until the desired height is reached. On landing the charges would then be equalised without and within.

**TLDR:** In other words, the robot makes a series of many sparks big-enough to blow it into the air on a cushion of plasma.

*Stand well clear.*

Comment: Genius. Never would have thought of this, but the concept is amazing. (And dangerous, but since this is for a video game character with no humans, it should be fine...)

Comment: This idea would lead to some sweet game mechanics.  Lightning levitation the first.  Lightning repulsion of nonfixed objects the second.  Lightning as an attack,  Lightning into a conductor, to emerge elsewhere.  You could call the game "Ball Lightning".

Comment: @Willk Genius. I might make a seperate game of that!

Answer (score 7):

**Springs and winches and a deformable shell**

So basically your bot will be its core + an omnidirectionl amount of springs + an amount of electric motor-powered winches that are equal to and connected to the amount of springs + a rubber or some other deformable but tough enough material shell.

The winches would coil and store power in the springs and then release and uncoil to let the springs themselves uncoil and lead to a force imparted through the shell onto whatever surface, making the ball bot jump. Depending the amount of its sensory devices and the extent of its prediction algorithms the bot may even be able to use bouncing around as its main mode of locomotion instead of rolling though it would still be capable of rolling around anyway by the proper sequences of spring retraction and uncoiling. Add some winch locks and the ball bot would be able to lock in place its bottom or whatever spring while coiled, deforming its shell to have a 'flat' side and allowing it to stay at rest instead of rolling around on unstable or uneven ground.

Comment: As the OP has made this character for a video game, this allows in-game squash/stretch to telegraph that the bot will attempt a jump. Players may find this more intuitive and it may have game play ramifications.

Answer (score 6):

Your robot is 1 1/2 units in diameter, and needs to jump 1 unit. If the center of gravity as moved very near the (current) top position, then very quickly moved towards the (current) down position, the movement of the center relative to the shell would mean that in response the shell must move up. if the moveable core is much heavier than the shell, this should result in your desired jumping motion.
Since the jump height is less than the travelling distance of the core, it should be possible to achieve the desired height without using flexibility of the shell.

A side note: a flexible shell, and/or a lot of "legs" that can protrude when needed would seem a more sensible design in my opinion, since it would allow your robot to remain at rest without constantly applying energy, even in a situation that would be unstable for a perfect sphere.

Answer (score 5):

Some guys in Shenzen are developing an actual hopping spherical robot. [You can find the paper in ResearchGate for the specifics](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224118750_A_Spherical_Hopping_Robot_for_Exploration_in_Complex_Environments). In layman terms it uses gears to throw mass around inside itself, and then clever usage of Newton's third law enables it to leap not just upwards but also in many different angles. Here is an excerpt:

> The basic principle of the hopping robot is as follows: first, to drive the energy storage mechanism and accelerate the driving components attached to the mechanism; then the driving components will collide and connect with the follow-up parts of the robot; finally the whole robot jumps at a certain speed abiding by the energy balance principle.

If you are willing to allow your robot to deform, you can also take a page from [existing spherical leaping robots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EBUy0gyE38). Just put a shell over them.

---

By the way, in the absence of both [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) and [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) tags, you could also place a cat and a slice of buttered bread inside the ball. When you want the robot to jump, connect the unbuttered side of the bread slice to the back of the cat. This generates an anti-gravity engine. Now connect the mouth and anus of the cat to the inside wall of the robot by using a couple rods and the whole robot will have its mass reduced. Inside an atmosphere this means the lift on the spherical surface will be much greater than the robot's weight, causing it to go up really fast. Disconnect the bread from the cat to have the robot come down again.

Comment: Oh, neat! Great minds think alike.

Answer (score 4):

**Using rotating masses to release a lot of  kinetic energy instantly:**

Sounds a bit like a more mobile version of the MASCOT experiment: https://www.dlr.de/irs/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-11302/#gallery/28470 and https://www.dlr.de/content/en/articles/missions-projects/mascot/mascot-lander.html

The DLR stops a rotating mass to launch this box off an asteroid surface. With more energy and 3 of those flywheels you could angle the jump in any direction. Needs a recharge time of course to spin the flywheels back up.

Maybe you could combine this with a linear stage as proposed by [@Gault Drakkor](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/223562/30492)

Answer (score 3):

**Microfluidic
ElectroSpray
Propulsion**

This is a recently discovered form of propulsion generated by using an indium pool drawn through hundreds of needles by an electromagnetic field. The surface tension pulls the melted indium back down, allowing this to function in zero-G. The indium forms into hundreds of tiny cones, the tips of which are overcome by the electromagnetic field, ionized as they pass through, and shoot outward at tens of kilometers per second. If you used a metal with low mass nuclei and weak hydrogen bonding, the ionized particles could pass though the shell and propel the bot "up" because of the sheer number of ionized indium particles racing away at once.

Comment: If the atoms are ejected, it's nothing different than a rocket, to which OP said no.

Comment: But there are no holes in the actual shell of the bot.

Comment: But I see what you mean. sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of how to make this work has been provided in a few answers already, but I thought I'd supplement those answers with some calculations to figure out the rough engineering constraints.

We'll base the calculations on the robot containing a linear rail with a weight on it, and a motor capable of moving this weight up and down with a constant force.

To make a jump, the weight will start at the bottom of the rail, then be accelerated upwards with the constant force, and slam into the top of the robot. This will transfer the momentum from the weight to the whole robot, which will then jump upwards.

I'll assume that the robot is $m_r$ = 6.8 kg (15 lb), $d_r$ = 0.45 m in diameter (1.5 ft), and should jump a minimum of $h_{min}$ = 0.3 m (1.5 ft). Also I'll assume a gravity of $g$ = 9.81 m/s².

Our main design variables are the length of the rail, $d$, the mass of the weight, $m$, and the force it is moved with $F$. The length of the rail and mass of the weight are obviously constrained by the mass and diameter of the robot respectively.

First, we'll set up an equation for the momentum the system can generate. If the weight is moved the maximum distance with the given force, it will end up with a momentum of $$p_{max} = \sqrt{F \, m \, d}$$ right before it hits the top of the rail. When this momentum is transferred to the whole robot, it's velocity will become $$v_r = \frac{p_{max}}{m_r} = \frac{\sqrt{F \, m \, d}}{m_r}$$

Since we want a minimum jump height, we can now figure out how high this velocity will propel the robot. This comes out to be $$h = \frac{v_r^2}{2 g} = \frac{F \, m \, d}{2 \, m_r \, g}$$

If we set $h = h_{min}$ and rearrange the terms,  we get the design equation $$F \, m \, d = 2 \, g \, m_r^2 \, h_{min}$$ which tells us that the product of our three main design variables must equal a constant proportional to the desired jump height.

To take an example, lets choose the rail length to be $d$ = 0.3 m (1 ft), and  the mass of the weight to be $m$ = 4 kg (8.8 lb). This gives us a required force of $$\frac{2 \times 9.81 \text{ms}^{-2} \times (6.8 \text{kg})^2 \times 0.3 \text{m}}{4 \text{kg} \times 0.3 \text{m}} \approx 227 \text{N} $$

Another important number to engineer this system is the power requirement for the motor, as this will determine the dimensioning of a lot of the power-train components. Since the robot mass and jump height are given, the total energy requirement is simply equal to $$E = m_r \, g \, h_{min} = 6.8\text{kg} \times 9.81 \text{ms}^{-2} \times 0.3 \text{m} \approx 20.3\text{J}$$

If we assume no energy is lost to friction, deformation, etc., we can get the power simply by dividing the total energy by the time it takes for the weight to reach the top of the rail. This comes out to $$t = \sqrt{\frac{d \, m}{F}}$$ giving us a power requirement of $$P = \frac{E}{t} = m_r \, g \, h_{min} \sqrt{\frac{F}{d \, m}}$$

Using the same numbers as the example above, the time comes to $$t = \sqrt{\frac{0.3 \text{m} \times 4 \text{kg}}{227 \text{N}}} \approx 0.063 \text{s}$$ which requires a power of $$P = \frac{E}{t} = \frac{20.3\text{J}}{0.063\text{s}} \approx 322.8\text{W}$$

All in all, the numbers work out to this being quite feasible. Since the time of 63 ms to move the weight 1 ft is quite quick, it might not be feasible to build this with a motor and a ball-screw, or a belt, or something like that, but I would guess that for instance a linear induction motor could be up to the task.

Comment: The weight doesn't need to slam into the top of the sphere, it just needs to exert force on it in some way, for example by pulling a handle attached to the interior bottom of the sphere or applying a braking force to the rail.

Answer (score 1):

There is one that is cube shaped. Although not practical, I think same mechanism can be applied to spheres as suggested by others. [Here](https://robohub.org/swiss-robots-cubli-a-cube-that-can-jump-up-balance-and-walk-across-your-desk/) is the device in fully working state. Sides can be closed without affecting its performance.